# Check if instances have occurred minimum once, every year in a specific range

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL I'm tasked with a big dataset, with data from 1970 to 2010. 
I want to check for consistency: *check if each instance occurs minimum one time per year*. I took a snippet from 1970-1972 as example to demonstrate my problem.

input:

```
id  year    counts
--  ----    ---------
1   1970    1
1   1971    1
2   1970    3
2   1971    8
2   1972    1
3   1970    4
```

expected:

```
id  1970-1972
--  ----------
1   no
2   yes
3   no
```

I though about counting within the date range and then taking those out who had 3 counts: 1970, 1971, 1972. The following query doesn't force the check on each point in the range though.

```
select id, count(*)
from table1
WHERE (year BETWEEN '1970' AND '1972') AND `no_counts` >= 1
group by id
```

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `CASE` / inline `if`.

Using `CASE`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f0df6/3)

```
select id,CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct year) = 3 THEN 'yes'ELSE 'No' END "1970-72"
from abc
WHERE year between 1970 and 1972
GROUP BY id
```

Using inline `IF`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f0df6/5)

```
select id,IF( COUNT(distinct year) = 3,'yes','No') "1970-72"
from abc
WHERE year between 1970 and 1972
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: is not having is much better idea then case ?

Comment: @Dhaval - `having` will give you only records which have records in each year. OP also wants to show `No` if there are missing records. that is why i am using `CASE` and not `HAVING`

Comment: Can't I specify a date range with this one? Im trying this query with my entire dataset (1970-2010) which is 36 distinct years and it turns no to all. If I do a >=36, then I start seeing some 'yes' values.

Comment: Yes, actually I created a sample fiddle with this specific data. added the filter to the answer

Comment: Have not noticed _OP's_ desired output – this answer fits much better, I don't understand the reason it is not voted . *P.S.you can also shorten your answer a little by using inline `if` instead of `case` expression.*

Comment: @notulysses - Thanks, added an example with _inline if_ a well

Comment: This answer suits the expected output perfect.

Comment: @ughai u r right i missed OP's point  which u told me thnks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `having` clause with `distinct` count:

```
select `id`
from `table1`
where `year` between '1970' and '1972'
group by id
having count(distinct `year`) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect this?

```
select id, count(*)
from table1
WHERE (year BETWEEN '1970' AND '1972')
group by id
having count(distinct year) = 3
```

Comment: no OP is not asking for this .. what he is  asking at least 1 id in each year

Comment: Well, let OP decide. I think this delivers each ID which is present in 3 different years.